# How can I make input data for logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, predictive-models, descriptive-statistics

I have dataset with 6 category variables. each category variable shows some machine error codes ranging between 0 and some big number like 50000. I want to try Logistic Regression to build a predictive model with a binary outcome.

As far as I know, Logistic Regression can accept and handle any combinations of category, binary, and numeric data types. What concerns me is that values of each category variable varies too large.

I have added another variable, weekofday, that just indicates the day of the week like Monday, Tuesday, and etc.. I have mapped those days to [0 to Monday, 1 to Tuesday, 2 to WendesDay, 3 to Thursday, 4 to Friday, 5 to Saturday, 6 to Sunday].

I want to understand the right way with making right input feature with category variables with large category values.

I have attached the data with my question. Hope to get some answers.
[data link to my question](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Uo2eB4Isl37XlLgfPmA_H03S8IcQAMet)

Comment: I think you intended to attach a different link, the one you have attached is of a tutorial on BNs.
What binary outcome would you want for the machine error codes?

Comment: Could you explain in what sense a variable like day of the week is "large" and why that might matter for performing logistic regression?

Comment: I just fixed the link to dataset. 

The day of the week is not a big deal compare to other category values because it only goes from 0 to 6. But other category values are really small and large. Those category values shows error codes. Does Logistic Regression get affected by big numbers even from large category values?

I thought about turn them into binary variables for each sub error code but if I do that, then the number of variables goes up to more than 2,000 variables. I don't know if this is going to be find or not. And, in what form can I feed dataset into Logistic Regression?